# Could not find appcompat_v7

Tags: android

```
[2014-12-03 12:05:01 - DynamicTableLayout] Android Launch!
[2014-12-03 12:05:01 - DynamicTableLayout] adb is running normally.
[2014-12-03 12:05:01 - DynamicTableLayout] Performing com.pavan.dynamictablelayout.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-12-03 12:05:01 - DynamicTableLayout] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5556' running compatible AVD 'deneme2'
[2014-12-03 12:05:02 - DynamicTableLayout] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-12-03 12:05:02 - appcompat_v7] Could not find appcompat_v7.apk!
[2014-12-03 12:05:02 - DynamicTableLayout] Starting activity com.pavan.dynamictablelayout.MainActivity on device emulator-5556
[2014-12-03 12:05:03 - DynamicTableLayout] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.pavan.dynamictablelayout/.MainActivity }
```

---

```
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:42: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:52: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:57: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:61: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:65: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:70: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] C:\Users\Gizem\Desktop\DynamicTableLayout\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] 
[2014-12-03 13:27:28 - DynamicTableLayout] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
```

Comment: you can get this library from here : \sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat

Comment: This is a same question like I answered before. Try to open it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27229003/3922207

Answer (score 0):

just followed the Support [Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) on the android site.

Comment: my program didnt see my xml files